# php - Sum of two times ( HH:MM:SS)

Tags: php

i have  4 date time

```
   datatime1= 2018-10-01 13:00:00
   datatime2= 2018-10-01 13:59:00
   datatime3= 2018-10-01 14:29:00
   datatime4= 2018-10-01 15:29:00
```

so  i need to get this result

> PART1: datatime[2]-datatime[1] = **0:59:0**
>
> PART2: datatime[3]-datatime[2] = **0:30:0**
>
> PART3: datatime[4]-datatime[3] = **1:0:0**
>
> PART4: PART1 + PART3 = **1:59:0**

Idk if this is right way but i can get result for *Part1, Part2* and 
*Part3* but i dont know how to get result for *PART4*

```
 $time1 = new DateTime('2018-10-01 13:00:00');
 $time2 = new DateTime('2018-10-01 13:59:00');
 $time3 = new DateTime('2018-10-01 14:29:00');
 $time4 = new DateTime('2018-10-01 15:29:00');


$part1= date_diff($time2,$time1)->format('%h:%i:%s');
$part2= date_diff($time3,$time2)->format('%h:%i:%s');
$part3= date_diff($time4,$time3)->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

Comment: Look like PASRT4 = PART1 +PART3 from end result. Don't know if it was a typo.

Comment: I might be wrong, but what about converting them into timestamp to make operations on it, then format it as you want ? Otherwise, you can use function `date_add()`

Comment: its part1 + part3 sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and set it to for example to midnight `00:00:00`. [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) returns a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) which you can add to the Datetime. Finally get the diff from midnight again.

```
$part4 = (new DateTime('midnight'))
    ->add(date_diff($time2, $time1))
    ->add(date_diff($time4,$time3))
    ->diff(new DateTime('midnight'))
    ->format('%h:%i:%s');

echo $part4; // 1:59:0
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/J8I6r)

Comment: this is ok and i get 1:59:0,  but is there any simple way that i can follow on other scenarions , example i have 15 times and i need to sum all those  in HH:MM:SS so ill get total h,m,s of all 15 times

Comment: how can it be just HH MM SS not days

Comment: @Gloytoshtyqo One way could be to get the days and multiply by 24 to get the hours https://3v4l.org/NF6vM

Answer (score 2):

**I am assuming that your example is wrong since part1 + part2 would result in 1:29 not 1:59.**

Explanation can be found as comments in the code.

```
<?php

 $time1 = new DateTime('2018-10-01 13:00:00');
 $time2 = new DateTime('2018-10-01 13:59:00');
 $time3 = new DateTime('2018-10-01 14:29:00');
 $time4 = new DateTime('2018-10-01 15:29:00');


$part1= $time1->diff($time2)->format('%h:%i:%s');
$part2= $time2->diff($time3)->format('%h:%i:%s');
$part3= $time3->diff($time4)->format('%h:%i:%s');

$part4 = new DateTime('00:00'); // Create a 00:00 DateTime so we can use it for calculation
$part4Clone = clone $part4;
$part4->add($time1->diff($time2)); // Add $part1 (difference between $time1 and $time2)
$part4->add($time2->diff($time3)); // Add $part2 (difference between $time2 and $time3)
$part4 = $part4->diff($part4Clone)->format('%h:%i:%s'); // Calculate difference between 00:00 and $part1+$part2 and format it accordingly

var_dump($part1,$part2,$part3,$part4);
```

https://3v4l.org/B8Im8

> Output for 5.6.38 - 7.3.0rc4
>
> string(6) "0:59:0"
>
> string(6) "0:30:0"
>
> string(5) "1:0:0"
>
> string(6) "1:29:0"

Comment: is there any simple way  like this 0:59:0 + 1:0:0 =, coz i already know how much H:i:s is the first part and how much is the second part